# Is there possibility to enable file path autocompletion in PyCharm?

Tags: python, path, pycharm

I'm looking for an option to enable file path autocompletion in *Python* scripts for *PyCharm*. Is there such an option or a plug-in?

A similar feature exists already in *Jupyter Notebook*:
[image: jupyter-example]

Comment: File path completion is supported by PyCharm, does not it suggest anything in the case above?

Comment: @user2235698 As I wrote, the shown example is taken from *Jupyter Notebook*.

Comment: @user2235698 Of course, seems obvious... Especially, when variables autocompletion works well for me in *PyCharm*. Firstly (**before** posting the question), I assumed it to be an error because paths autocompletion, like variables autocompletion, seems to be quite basic feature, but I couldn't find any person with a similar problem.  Anyway, the plugin suggested by Navneet Singh works perfectly and I didn't find easier solution so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible, however you need to use plugin for that.
you can find it [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11088-file-path-autocomplete)